# Masking out two bits at the time

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, mask

I'm having a hard time working with bits and bytes in general, but I have an assignment where I have to mask out n number of bits at the time, and I don't know how to go about it. Say I have the binary number 1011010, and I want the most significant 2 bits (10). Then I want the next 2 bits (11), then the next 2, and so on, until all bits have been processed. So the mask would first be 1100000, then 0011000, etc. I know I can get the least significant bits by shifting n indexes and subtracting 1, but how do I do it the other way?

I have int mask = ((1 << NUM_BIT)-1) * (NUM_BIT*2);, where NUM_BIT is the number of bits I'm masking (2 currently) but this is not working on bytes longer than 4 bits, and I don't know how to move the 1 bits down...

Comment: ``where I have to mask out n number of bits at the time``, exemplify please, which ``n`` bits ?

Comment: Edited to clarify a bit - basically I want the 2 most significant bits, then the next 2 most significant, and so on until all bits have been processed. So I'd want a mask that goes 1100000, then 0011000, then 0000110, and finally just 000001

Comment: `-1 << (32 - n)` would be a mask, `x << n` would shift n places; `x >>> 32 - n` would shift the right most bits to the focus. And Integer has many nice bit methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be this:

```
int i = 4; // number of bits you want to mask
int mask = ~((1 << 32 - i) - 1); // will return 11110000000000000000000000000000
```

Then you just "move" the bits to the right, until `mask` is `0`.
Example :

```
while (mask != 0) {
     String replace = String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(mask)).replace(' ', '0'); // just to be more clear
     System.out.println(replace);
     mask = mask >>> i;
}
```

Output:

```
11110000000000000000000000000000
00001111000000000000000000000000
00000000111100000000000000000000
00000000000011110000000000000000
00000000000000001111000000000000
00000000000000000000111100000000
00000000000000000000000011110000
00000000000000000000000000001111
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

If you want two bits, just replace `i` with 2;

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code:

```
public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int inputInt = Integer.parseInt("1011010", 2);
        twoBits(inputInt);
    }
    public static void twoBits(int inputInt) {
        int mask = 3<<30;
        while(mask != 0 && (inputInt & mask)==0) {
            mask >>>= 2;
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(inputInt)).replace(' ', '0'));
        do {
            System.out.println(String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString(inputInt & mask)).replace(' ', '0'));
            mask >>>= 2;
        }
        while(mask != 0 && (inputInt & mask)!=0);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
00000000000000000000000001011010
00000000000000000000000001000000
00000000000000000000000000010000
00000000000000000000000000001000
00000000000000000000000000000010
```